# Как отключить функции магазина в Magento?

Tags: magento

Как убрать функции магазина с кнопками "В корзину" или только через css `display: none;` ? Корзину отключил в админке - Mage_Checkout: отключить.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Есть шаблон в котором выводятся кнопки добавить в корзину.

Вот несколько вариантов как убрать кнопку:

1. Заккоментить в самом шаблоне вывод (т.к. этот шаблон по дефолту выводится) - ../app/design/frontend/theme/package/template/catalog/product/view/addtocart.phtml
2. Закомментить в слое catalog.xml ту часть что добавляет этот шаблон в карточке товара в секции  вот сам код который добавляет шаблон:

   ```
     <block type="catalog/product_view" name="product.info.addto" as="addto" template="catalog/product/view/addto.phtml">
       <block type="core/text_list" name="alert.urls" as="alert_urls" translate="label">
           <label>Alert Urls</label>
       </block>
   ```